# WSO2 ESB. File transfer with trailer checking

Tags: wso2-esb

My WSO2 ESB has to copy large files (>100MB) from one directory to another. Earlier, when pollInterval was 5 seconds, a file wasn't completely copied. I set pollInterval to 180 seconds, and everything is ok now. But I need a guarantee, that file will be copied completely. There is a trailer at the end of file. So, I just need to check, is there a trailer at the end of copied file or not. Is it possible?

My **esb_configuration.xml**

```
<proxy name="proxy_name" transports="vfs" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.Streaming">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">180</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">DELETE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">vfs:file:///path/to/file</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterErrors">DELETE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">^FILE_MASK$</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">application/octet-stream</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">DELETE</parameter>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Poll Interval doesn't affect the files that are being transferred, it just acts as a scheduler for the transport receiver to poll the file URI location. Are you sure the file didn't get copied completely due to the poll interval being less?

I don't think there are any ways of checking the trailer record using the VFS parameters.
Maybe you can use `transport.vfs.MaxRetryCount` to retry in case of any failures, you can see the complete list of VFS service level parameters [1].

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/VFS+Transport#VFSTransport-parametersVFSservice-levelparameters